# Mark function as noexcept based on template argument

Tags: c++, templates, noexcept

Take this code:

```
template <class T>
void my_func() { T::some_method(); }

int main() {
    std::cout << (noexcept(my_func<SomeClass>()) ? "noexcept" : "can throw") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will always print out that `my_func()` can throw, even if `SomeClass::some_method()` is marked as [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). (at least with gcc 7.4.0 and -std=c++17)

Is there a practical way to make the compiler detect if the function is `noexcept` or not depending on the template argument ?

The only one that I can think of is using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) :

```
template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<true == noexcept(T::some_method())>
my_func() noexcept { T::some_method(); }

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<false == noexcept(T::some_method())>
my_func() { T::some_method(); }
```

But it takes a lot of space and causes code repetition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`noexcept` specifications have a version taking a boolean.

```
template <class T>
void my_func() noexcept(noexcept(T::some_method())) { T::some_method(); }
```

Now it will be conditionally noexcept, based on the expression `T::some_method()`.